# Create histogram in Python

Tags: python, pandas, list, matplotlib

I have found a few useful discussions on Stack Overflow, however, I am not using a list of values, yet a list of columns from a large dataset that I would like to apply a histogram to. I just want to quickly explore my data.

Dataframe consists of 18 columns, 12330 rows. I have created a list of columns as you can see below. I would like to create a hist through the use of a function that plots a hist (one for each column) in separate windows. The problem I face is implementing the logic to iterate through all columns, plotting a hist.

Here is a link to my df: Values are both discrete and continuous, and also strings (you can see the first 30 or so rows)

https://ibb.co/PhQ5vsn

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as plt


df = pd.read_csv("removed file path for sake of space")
columns = df.columns.tolist()

"""data exploration functions for visualising data"""

def histogram ():
    for i in columns: 
        plt.hist(columns)
    return
```

My function was just me playing around with some ideas. No sure how to iterate through each column and plot individually, rather than a mass in one image.

I am in need of some ideas on how to iterate through this list to then apply a chart of my choosing, in this case, a histogram. The focus is primarily the aforementioned.

Comment: Please have a looks to the some already created functions for this or similar, perhaps that could help :) : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.hist.html

Comment: Cheers Rafael, I'll take a look but may come back here for feedback or help; need be

Comment: `for i in hist_col_list: plt.hist(df[col])`?

Comment: @QuangHoang something like this for sure, But as of now, its plotting all data on one histogram, rather than 18 individual histograms. Which here lies my problem.

Comment: Add `plt.show()` inside `for` loop. Also, you can do something like `df.plot.hist(layout=(3,6))` without the for loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly iterate over DataFrame objects.

```
for col in df:
    df[col].plot(kind="hist")
```

You will need to drop your text columns before you do this.

Here's a full example in case it helps. I'm plotting all the histograms on one plot, but you can change the behavior however you like.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mwaskom/seaborn-data/master/iris.csv')
print(df.head())
df = df.drop("species",axis=1)
print(df.head())
for col in df:
    df[col].plot(kind="hist")
lgd = plt.legend()
```

This is the output:

```
   sepal_length  sepal_width  petal_length  petal_width species
0           5.1          3.5           1.4          0.2  setosa
1           4.9          3.0           1.4          0.2  setosa
2           4.7          3.2           1.3          0.2  setosa
3           4.6          3.1           1.5          0.2  setosa
4           5.0          3.6           1.4          0.2  setosa

   sepal_length  sepal_width  petal_length  petal_width
0           5.1          3.5           1.4          0.2
1           4.9          3.0           1.4          0.2
2           4.7          3.2           1.3          0.2
3           4.6          3.1           1.5          0.2
4           5.0          3.6           1.4          0.2
```

[image]

To get each column in a separate plot, change the for loop like this:

```
for col in df:
    df[col].plot(kind="hist")
    plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: thats great, and how would you plot each histogram in seperate windows? You have a hist that contains 4 sets of data, but if you were to plot the same data individually, how would you implement this?

Comment: Add `plt.show()` at the end of the for loop to show each one separately. So instead of one line in the for loop, you'll have two.

Comment: I just updated the answer with that edit.

Comment: thats great, got the data visualised. Could i wrap thisup inside a UDF? I think the next step is to organise each plot with if statements to get an idea of what exactly is going on

Comment: If I were going to call this more than once I would certainly want it in a function. I'm not sure where you're going with the if statements though.

Comment: To elaborate, not all data is numeric, there is data that value : true or false for example. Since what you have come up with (which im thankfuil for) works for 11 out of 18 columns.

Comment: I understand now. Yes, that's when you will need to weed them out with a `.drop` or something.  You could also just filter by columns and only loop over a slice of the dataframe with the ones you want to plot.